# GDB 7.11 start error

Tags: c++, gdb, freebsd

I've installed gdb 7.11 via, pkg install gdb-7.11 ...
When I try to run it, gdb gives me this error;

```
i386fbsd-kern.c:482: internal-error: _initialize_i386_kgdb_tdep: Assertion `offsetof(struct pcb, pcb_ebx) == i386fbsd_pcb_offset[I386_EBX_REGNUM]' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]

This is a bug, please report it.  For instructions, see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.

i386fbsd-kern.c:482: internal-error: _initialize_i386_kgdb_tdep: Assertion `offsetof(struct pcb, pcb_ebx) == i386fbsd_pcb_offset[I386_EBX_REGNUM]' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Create a core file of GDB? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
Abort (core dumped)
```

I can't debug my core files, because I'm using g++ 4.9 compiler, so I should use 7.11...

My system: FreeBSD local.com 9.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE #0 r255898: Fri Sep 27 03:52:52 UTC 2013     root@bake.isc.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  i386

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've installed fresh freebsd 10.3 x86 and installed gdb 7.11 but, still same error! weird.

Comment: I reproduced this error on x86 (32 bit). Building from source (`/usr/ports/devel/gdb`) produces a working version.

Comment: Yes, thank you, when I reproduce from ports, it's worked, It's weird ...

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looked like an ABI problem, but it's more like GDB is doing something really stupid: it tries to use kernel backend for the kernel version it doesn't know about, even though it doesn't need the backend at all - since you're debugging userspace, not the kernel.

You should submit a PR about this (http://bugs.freebsd.org).